# JSP exception for component already used in view

Tags: java, jsp, websphere

I get this exception in my java application running on WAS 8.5:

> Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Component ID 'ResultURL' has already been used in the view.

I assumed it meant some jsp had more than one component with ResultURL for the ID but I cheked and there is only one jsp file containing this and no sign of a duplicate. What could be causing this?

This is the component:

```
<h:inputHidden id="ResultURL" value="http://localhost:9080/HP_Web/DefaultLoginServlet"/>
```

Comment: Could you be including the file multiple times, either directly or indirectly?

Comment: Probably a silly question but how would I check this?

Comment: Well, you could trace all imports and includes manually or maybe there's some tool which I don't know. More pragmatically, you could try to add some special output to the jsp, comment out the tags that give issues until the page renders and then look for the special output (e.g. some text) in the resulting page (use the browers dev tools). If you find the special sequence once the jsp should be included only once, if you don't find it you probably did it wrong and the output was not rendered, if you find it multiple times the position should give you a hint where to look further.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I was thinking last night that this code is running in other environments so multiple includes may not be the issue. Def worth ruling out though. Is there any possibility of something like a caching issue on WAS?

Comment: If the exact same code is running on another application server then this could be something specific to WAS. I can't imagine it would be a caching issue but I can't rule it out as well. Try to look for patterns, e.g. do you have other tags of the same type, does it work with a different id, does it work with a different value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the application, the original line had been commented out and a new line added. The webserver didn't seem to recognise the code comment though so thought there was two lines with the same ID. When I removed the commented out line the error disappeared.